# Cannot display about 2000-2500 markers on Google Maps API v3

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3

I have a table that contains about 2500 records and each record have their respective Latitude and Longitude values. Next is that i'm retrieving all the Latitude and Longitude values of each record and displaying the markers on google maps version 3. The code works fine if i select top let's say 200-250 records. But when i select all rows the markers do not display.In fact the map itself does not display.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = this.GetData("select top 250 * from tblEarthquake");
            rptMarkers.DataSource = dt;
            rptMarkers.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EarthquakeCS"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCxHKyDx5Kl4XJBRdau_kbTqB_G5gB-z2c&sensor=false"></script>
<%--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var markers = [
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
        {
        "title": '<%# Eval("Location") %>',
        "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
        "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>',
        "description": '<%# Eval("Magnitude") %>'
        }
    </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
        ,
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    ];
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 8//,
            //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
    }
</script>

<div id="dvMap" style="width: auto; height: 500px">
</div>
```

Comment: If the map doesn't display either, then it is likely that a JavaScript error has occurred. There's probably some data that isn't escaped properly in your Repeater output and therefore there's a syntax error (e.g a place name with a `'` in it). Take a look at your console in your browser to see if there are any errors. Furthermore, you should take a look at using a `ashx` handler file to retrieve the marker data in JSON format. The `Newtonsoft JSON.NET` library is very good at automatically serializing datatables into JSON format

Comment: Sorry for late reply...yeah in fact there isn't any errors but some warnings that appear like "," is expected...and ";" is expected

Comment: What does your generated client-side javascript look like, for the part where you create the markers?   You may want to post a link to an external site where we can see the list of 2000+ markers

Answer (score 0):

The lat/lng values for markers should be floating point numbers.  You're wrapping them in `'...'` i.e. creating strings.

Change:

```
{
    "title": '<%# Eval("Location") %>',
    "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
    "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>',
    "description": '<%# Eval("Magnitude") %>'
}
```

to:

```
{
    "title": '<%# Eval("Location") %>',
    "lat": <%# Eval("Latitude") %>,
    "lng": <%# Eval("Longitude") %>,
    "description": '<%# Eval("Magnitude") %>'
}
```